# excel is turning my dates which are custom formatted into numbers when used in a formula

Tags: excel

I am using a formula to create a series of insert statements to use in SQL. However, when I do this, dates that are part of the spreadsheet (which are formatted dd-mmm-yy and needs to be like this) are changed to numbers when I use a formula. Sorry, tried to explain this the best I could, anyone know a way around this?

My formula is below

```
="INSERT INTO trip VALUES ("&N1&", '"&O1&"', '"&P1&"', '"&Q1&"', '"&R1&"');"
```

And an example of what I will get back is

```
INSERT INTO trip VALUES (72952, '40911','40919', 'BD08AOG', '0080919');
```

40911 should read 03-Jan-12 and 40919 should read 11-Jan-12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the dates using this:

```
="INSERT INTO trip VALUES ("&TEXT(N1,"dd-mmm-yy")...
```

`TEXT(N1,"dd-mmm-yy")` will apply your format.